# Google cloud speech npm permission denied (publickey)

Tags: node.js, npm, raspbian

I'm trying to use the google cloud speech API with node.js. After setting it up in the google developer console, i'm trying to download the npm with: `sudo npm install --save @google-cloud/speech` as the documentation says. however i keep getting the error:

`npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:google-cloud/speech permission denied (publickey)`

I'm still quite new at linux so i'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong or what the problem even could be. All i could think of is update software and try again, but the problem persists.

After some digging around i've seen some things about checking if my ssh keys are proper, which is where i'm really confused. i know its a certificate shared between server and client, but where do i get it? how do i add it? how do i even check if they are properly set? how do i even know?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

[link to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/speech)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns our raspbian comes packed with npm 1.4, i needed 2.7 at least to make use of scoped packages, recognizable by the @.

First i removed all packages associated with node/npm.

```
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove nodered -y
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-legacy -y
root@raspberrypi:~ # apt-get remove npm  -y
```

Then

```
root@raspberrypi:~ # curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install nodejs -y
root@raspberrypi:~# node -v
v5.12.0
root@raspberrypi:~# npm -v
v4.4.4
```